# An svg within a button is overlaying the text, but I need it to float right within button

Tags: html, css, button, svg

I have a simple button that contains the word "Send" as well as a small paper plane icon. This icon is positioned properly when viewed in Chrome, but when viewed in Internet Explorer the svg (paper plane) is overlaying the text. **How do I make the paper plane float the right of the button in Internet Explorer?**

Here's a link to the [page on my server](http://taskbasket.net/public/)
Heres the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaLwbr)

The HTML for the button is:

```
 <button>
 <!-- <p>Fire Away!</p>-->
   <p>Ready, Aim...</p>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path> 
  </svg>
</button>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. `button` can not contain `p`. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://taskbasket.net/public/

Comment: Oh ok, what should I replace it with in order for the text to remain displayed as is?  Any feedback on the original problem would be great too. Thank you

Comment: Anything that it allowed in there, together with the appropriate CSS formatting to make it appear as you want it too.

Comment: Anything that is allowed in there.... like what? I can't use p tags or h1 tags it seems, what sort of tags do I put the text in? Can you give an example

Comment: The validator output links to an explanation what _phrasing content_ is already. Besides, who says you need an additional element in there in the first place? The text might as well be _direct_ content of the `button` element.

Comment: Oh ok thanks,  I fixed it. Any help on the original question would be great. Need to get the plane to float right within button in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style causes the problem in IE:

```
button svg {
  width: auto;
}
```

Hard-coding a width fixes it:

```
button svg {
  width: 30px;
}
```

Also, remove the `p` tag from the button.  [Buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) should contain non-interactive [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) only.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxjEeQ)

Comment: What a beautiful answer, simple and effective. Thanks Rick and everyone who contributed.

Comment: What's wrong with using p tag within buttons? It seemed to work just fine in all browsers... just curious

Comment: Browsers are very forgiving of things that aren't part of the standard.  It does seem odd that the standard allows `iframe`s but not `p`s as part of "phrasing content."  Running your HTML through a validator like @CBroe recommended is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the html syntaxes. Here's another approach to the problem.

Using anchor tag with svg attached to it.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/vfL0pyq5/2/

```
<a href="http://google.com/">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100">
    <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path> 
  </svg>
</a>
```

Of course, you need to apply the CSS for it.

Comment: I'm very new to this, and have no clue how to adapt that into the code I provided. Theres no button tag in your code, which is needed by my css code to produce the airplane effect. I simply need the paper plane in my original question to be floating to the right in Internet Explorer.....

Comment: The airplane image comes solely from your embedded SVG image; everything else “around” it is just formatting, and as such can be achieved with CSS alone on basically _any_ element. (The `button` element might come with some default formatting from the browser stylesheet – but nothing stops you from reproducing that same formatting for early any other element imaginable.)

Comment: I right-clicked on the plane and selected "Inspect Element" and then I changed it's margin-left to 50px and it didn't budge. So I don't know how to move the plane for Internet Explorer. Here's a screenshot showing what  I mean http://taskbasket.net/public/screenshot.png  No number of pixels makes it move, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you’ve set there, is a margin on the _path_ element inside the svg element. And you have absolutely positioned your svg, for which there should be no need to begin with – as an inline element following a text node, it would simply be next right to the text to begin with.